# echo an environment variable in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
TEXT="blah" echo $TEXT    #echoes nothing
```

I thought it might be because echo is a builtin, so I tried this:

```
TEXT="blah" `which echo` $TEXT    #still nothing
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell expands the variables *before* it runs the command, even before it runs the assignments.

Cf.

```
text=blah ; echo $text
```

or

```
text=blah eval 'echo $text'
```

The first one works because the assignment is run as a separate command. The second one works because `$text` is single-quoted which prevents its expansion when shell is processing the command; when `eval` is later running, the variable already has the value assigned.

Comment: OK, I see. So if TEXT had been "foo" beforehand,
`TEXT="blah" echo $TEXT`
would have been expanded to
`TEXT="blah" echo foo`
before being executed.

Comment: Exactly, and it's very easy to try: `text=blah; text=new echo $text`.